# Execute raw SQL after connect to database

Tags: python, database, django

How can I execute raw SQL after connect to database?
I need to run script once, after connect to DB.
Thanks.

UPD: question is not how to run raw SQL.

Comment: How do you *connect to the database*?

Comment: "UPD: question is not how to run raw SQL." Can you tell us what the question *is*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just visit the docs [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/).

It was I think the second match on google with "Django ORM".

*EDIT* See comments

If you look at [this Django page](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database) you see that MySQLdb (the underlying layer) also accepts an init_command option which is run immediately after a connection is established. That's a feature of MySQLdb, and not so much of Django itself.

Comment: sorry for the inaccuracy. I need to run a script once after connecting to db.

Comment: @histrio if the script can be used in the init_command (for instance calling a MySQL stored procedure) you can configure MySQLdb to run that. Otherwise some more details on the script are required.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using django >= 1.2:

```
from django.db import connection, transaction

query = "SELECT foo FROM bar;"
connection.cursor().execute(query)
transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```